# How can i make my text and first div get vertical aligned?

Tags: html, css, text, alignment, text-align

So i am doing this code to train, but i can't find a way to align my text with my div box. Also the code i'm also trying to make the div that contains everything else also get aligned vertically with the page.

```css
body{
  background-color: black;
}

.box{
  border-style: solid;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  margin: auto;
}

.boxInside{
  border-style: solid;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0px;

/*   align a div vertically within its parent element */
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

p{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="background-color: white;">  
  <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: gray;">
    <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: white;">
      <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: gray;">
        <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: white;">
          <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: gray;">
            <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: white;">
              <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: gray;">
                <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: white;">
                  <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: gray;">
                    <div style="">
                      <p>Testing Display</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I vertically align text in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-in-a-div)

Comment: actually i saw that before i posted my question, i've tried some of those ideas, but I couldn't make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use css `flex` OR `grid` property.

```css
body{
  background-color: black;
}
/* I used flex property */
.box{
  border-style: solid;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.boxInside{
  background-color:blue;
  padding:9px;
}
.boxInside > p{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="background-color: white;">  
  <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: gray;">
    <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: white;">
      <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: gray;">
        <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: white;">
          <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: gray;">
            <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: white;">
              <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: gray;">
                <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: white;">
                  <div class="boxInside" style="background-color: gray;">
                  <!--small change here -->
                  <!--common class added here-->
                    <div class="boxInside">
                      <p>Testing Display</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note :**  If you want deep-box illusion then turn padding from `px` to `%`.